# Have two lists, want to exclude list2 from list1

Tags: shell, awk, sed, perl, mysql

*List1*:

```
1,name1                   
2,name2                    
3,name3                  
4,name4                   
5,name5                  
6,name6                  
7,name7                  
8,name8                  
9,name9
```

*List2*:

```
3
13
14
6
1
7
15
26
```

I need output like:

```
2,name
4,name
5,name
8,name
9,name
```

The output should contain items from column #1 of *List1* which are not in *List2*.

*List1* and *List2* are not sorted but I will sort both lists if required.
*List1* has around 60,000 records and List2 contains 20,0000.
Need solution by using Linux shell or `mysql`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `bash` is used (otherwise, pre-sort the input files with `sort -o List1 List1` and `sort -o List2 List2` and use `List1 List2` instead of the process substitutions):

```
$ join -t, -v1 <( sort List1 ) <( sort List2 )
2,name2
4,name4
5,name5
8,name8
9,name9
```

This does a relational JOIN operation between your two files, sorting their contents first.  The `-t,` tells `join` to treat commas as the field delimiter, and with `-v1` we ask for the entries in the first file that does not join with any entry in the second.  The join happens by default on the first field of each file.

To strip off the last integer from this:

```
join -t, -v1 <( sort List1 ) <( sort List2 ) | sed 's/[0-9]*$//'
```

For a MySQL solution, you would have had to provide the SQL schema for the involved tables, but the resulting query would have looked something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE joinfield1 NOT IN (SELECT joinfield2 FROM table2);
```

Comment: I tried sorting both files but it is giving result as list 1 without excluding list2 records

Comment: Mysql solution tried,it still running for last 7 hours. May be because list 2 contains 20 lakhs records

Comment: @kcmakwana If the data looks exactly as in you question, and if you ran the `join` command exactly as I wrote it, it will work.  Let me know if the data has some other format.  As for the MySQL query, it will depend on your schema what the actual query should be and you would need the appropriate indexes for making it run faster.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -wvf List2 List1
```

Output:

```
2,name2
4,name4
5,name5
8,name8
9,name9
```

Comment: Grep solution also worked. Easy to remember too. Thanks a lot

Comment: @kcmakwana, Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next};a[$1] == 0'  List2  List1

2,name2                    
4,name4                   
5,name5                  
8,name8                  
9,name9
```

- `a[$1]++; next` : it saves the 1st field in an array. Then,
- `a[$1] == 0`: the else block will only be executed if this is the second file so we check whether field 1 of this file has already been seen (`a[$1]==0`).